# Stoke's Theorem proof notation.

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of Stoke's theorem. In this proof uses the following notation:
$$dy \hat{ } dz=\frac{\partial(y,z) }{\partial(u,v)}$$
What is this meaning? What is the meaning of this doing an integral?
$\int \frac{\partial(y,z) }{\partial(u,v)}$

It comes from:
$$\int_{S} curl(F) · n=\int_{\partial S} F$$
is equivalent to
$$\int_{S} (\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}) dy\hat{} dz+(\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}) dz\hat{} dx + (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}) dx\hat{} dy =\int_{\partial S} P dx+ Q dy + R dz$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try looking at a different proof, like this one:
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-c-line-integrals-and-stokes-theorem/session-92-proof-of-stokes-theorem/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_v13.3.pdf

Maybe this helps with understanding the notation: http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~fratus/Phys100A/Boris/282_jacob_(8).pdf